# Как оставить в колонке фрейма данных только слова из списка?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных

Есть список слов: `spisok = ["яблоко", "апельсин", "мандарин"]`. Есть фрейм данных с колонкой, в ячейках которой, текст:

```
df = pd.Series({'1': "яблоко апельсин лимон", 
                '2': "яблоко апельсин лимон", 
                '3': "киви апельсин лимон", 
                '4': "яблоко банан лимон"})
```

Нужно оставить в ячейках только слова из списка, должно получиться так:

```
df = pd.Series({'1': "яблоко апельсин", 
                '2': "яблоко апельсин", 
                '3': "апельсин", 
                '4': "яблоко"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Обычно переменную `df` используют для хранения фреймов, а не столбцов (pd.Series). Поэтому, чтобы избежать путаницы с названиями я создам другую переменную - `col` (столбец фрейма или `pd.Series`):

```
col = df.copy()
res = (col
       .str.split()
       .explode()
       .to_frame("col")
       .query("col in @spisok")
       .groupby(level=0)
       ["col"]
       .apply(lambda c: c.str.cat(sep=" ")))
```

результат:

```
In [167]: res
Out[167]:
1    яблоко апельсин
2    яблоко апельсин
3           апельсин
4             яблоко
Name: col, dtype: object
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё классно) Так и задумывалось, чтобы легче было представить, что требуется  и ответить)

Comment: @user376604, [как принято говорить "спасибо" на SO (StackOverflow) ;)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814)